# Trying to convert java if/else to loops

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm building a Java game as part of my university studies and am trying to convert a large number of if/else statements into loops.

The current, nonworking code is:

```
    public void kickBall() {
        if(ballDirection == 1) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
            {
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(bg_icon);
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][++ballPositionY].setIcon(ball_icon);
                if(y == baby2PositionY) {
                    gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(baby2_icon);
                    ballDirection = 2;
                }
            }
```

Eclipse console log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at CBabyBallBounce.kickBall(CBabyBallBounce.java:613)
    at CBabyBallBounce$14.actionPerformed(CBabyBallBounce.java:516)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

line 613 indicated is the second gamePosition line, and 516 is the method call, but i'm having trouble understanding what the issue is and how I would rectify it?

previous code if it is useful..

```
        if (ballPositionY == 1 && ballDirection == 1) {
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(bg_icon);
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][++ballPositionY].setIcon(ball_icon);
            }
            else if(ballPositionY == 2 && ballDirection == 1) {
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(bg_icon);
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][++ballPositionY].setIcon(ball_icon);
            }
etc..
```

gamePosition code - this is within a 13x16 GridLayout JPanel:

```
    private JButton gamePosition[][] = new JButton[13][16];
.....

    for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<16; j++)
        {
            JButton game_display = new JButton(bg_icon);
            game_display.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            game_display.setBorder(null);
            game_display.setFocusable(false);
            gamePosition[i][j] = game_display;
            gamePosition[i][j].setFocusable(false);

            if(j==8)
            {
                gamePosition[i][j].setIcon(wall_icon);
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: 16 is not a valid value for either `ballPositionX` or `++ballPositionY`

Comment: Since you're using the predecriment command ++ballPositionY, it increases ballPositionY to 16, This is really something that a debugger is really good at finding.

Comment: What's the initial value of ballPositionY? There are no enough information at the moment to solve your problem

Comment: I've added gamePosition to the snippet above, initial int ballPositionY value is 5

Comment: Why do you increment ballPositionY? This is most likely the cause of your bug, because when it gets to 16, it's out of bounds (arrays in Java go from 0 - length-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You haven't checked the bounds of the arrays.
2. You haven't checked for `null`.

Do it as follows:

```
public void kickBall() {
    if (ballDirection == 1) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 15 && ballPositionX < gamePosition.length
                && ballPositionY < gamePosition[ballPositionX].length
                && gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY] != null; y++) {
            gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(bg_icon);
            ballPositionY++;
            if (ballPositionY < gamePosition[ballPositionX] && gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY] != null) {
                gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(ball_icon);
                if (y == baby2PositionY) {
                    gamePosition[ballPositionX][ballPositionY].setIcon(baby2_icon);
                    ballDirection = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: had to tweak that slightly, but it seems to have fixed it, thankyou